# scHow to change Datepicker format Materializecss

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, materialize

I am trying to display and collect date is this format `'m/d/yyyy'` looking into document I tried constructing below code but it does not seem to work:-

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var delems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    var dinstances = M.Datepicker.init(delems,'m/d/yyyy');
});
```

The out put I am getting is default and not the one I constructed.

This is how it appears currently:- 
[image]

Comment: Show how you want your date to be formatted and how it appears.

Comment: i want my date to be `1/14/2020` but its showing `Jan 14 2020`

Comment: Are you using some framework or plain javascript?

Comment: its a plain javascript. Basically a google apps script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace :

```
var dinstances = M.Datepicker.init(delems,'m/d/yyyy');
```

with:

```
var dinstances = M.Datepicker.init(delems, {format:'m/d/yyyy'});
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for the problem?

Comment: Can you provide the link so I can check?

Comment: here is the [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-dazgrt) but java script is not working there.

Comment: Now you problem is somewhere else, formatting issue is solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214335/discussion-between-mask-and-heisaif).